# Pigeonhole Principle - Roulette Wheel

Tags: inequality, pigeonhole-principle

**Question** - A Roulette wheel is divided into 36 sectors. Each sector is assigned a random number from 1 to 36. Show that there are three consecutive sectors such that the sum of their assigned numbers is at least 56.

**My approach ->** (Proof by Contradiction)

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ be the numbers assigned to the 1st, 2nd, ..., nth sectors respectively. Assume that the sum of all three consequtive sectors is less than 56.

Thus,

$$
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 < 56 \\
a_2 + a_3 + a_4 < 56 \\
\vdots \\
a_{36} + a_1 + a_2 < 56
$$
Adding them all,
$$
\Longrightarrow 3(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{36}) < 56 \cdot 36 \\
\Longrightarrow 3 \frac{36 \cdot 37}{2} < 56 \cdot 36 \\
\Longrightarrow 111 < 112
$$
 (which is true and hence, unable to prove by contradiction)

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: @vishlgoel  If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were on the right track. It is correct that if the statement

> There are three consecutive sectors such that the sum of their assigned numbers is at least 56.

does not hold then
$$
 a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} < 56
$$
for $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. However, this estimate is not strong enough to obtain a contradiction. Since all $a_i$ are *integers* we have in fact
the better estimate
$$
 a_i + a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} \le 55 
$$
for all $i$. Adding these inequalities now gives a contradiction,
as desired:
$$
 3 \frac{36 \cdot 37}{2} \le 55 \cdot 36 
\Longrightarrow 1998 \le 1980 \, .
$$

---

*Remark:* Actually there must be three consecutive sectors on the
Roulette wheel whose number add up to at least **57,** see

> [A066385](https://oeis.org/A066385) 
>   Smallest maximum of sum of 3 consecutive terms in any arrangement of [1..n] in a circle.

in the *On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences* for the general 
question and more information. In particular it is listed that $a(36) = 57$.

Comment: But if I use <56 instead of <=55, the answer is different. The former concludes to 1998<2016 and the latter concludes to 1998<=1980. Where am I thinking wrong? My brain is so not working!

Comment: @vishalgoel: $1998 \le 1980$ is a false statement, this implies that the assumption is wrong.  $1998 < 2016$ is a true statement, that does not imply anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. I feel so stupid right now.

Answer (score 6):

Since the average value of $a_i=18.5$ the average value of the sum of triples is 55.5 thus exists at least one triple such that the sum is at least 56.